# How to find out which MOC concerned by NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange

Tags: ios, core-data, nsnotificationcenter, ios10

How can I recognize which MOC did change when receiving a `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` notification. Apparently `userInfo` employs a key `"managedObjectContext"`, but I have not found this one documented among other [keys](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1654659-nsmanagedobjectcontext_change_no).

The reason I am asking is that I need to trigger some action after a child MOC was saved. The trigger must fire only once, but it looks as if I receive the notification twice, perhaps once for the child MOC and once for its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the `object` property of the `NSNotification`.

```
- (void)contextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = notification.object;
}
```